# Laravel Eloquent - Does the relation having the relation?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a model Alpha which has many model Beta which has many model Charlie
I wan't all the beta from one alpha which have at least one charlie.

So my guess was :

```
$alpha = Alpha::first();
$betasWithACharlie = $alpha->betas()->has('charlies')->get();
```

But this doesn't work.
I also tried with "whereHas" unsuccessfully.

Comment: Just a tip: write the normal query first in some sql client like dbeaver or  heidiSQL. Next try to translate said query to Eloquent.

Comment: have you configured your model properly? FK should be in place for this to work. good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply:

```
$betasWithACharlie = $alpha->betas()->has('charlies', '>', 1)->get();
```

Or you can retrieve 'charlies' only if they fulfill a certain condition for more advanced queries

```
$betasWithACharlie = $alpha->betas()->whereHas('charlies', function($query){
$query->where('condition');
})->get();
```

Comment: Thats working, but strangely for one special case its give all the betas but not relative to the alpha one. (its give more result with the where condition than without)

Comment: check the foreign keys, there must be something while you populated the DB.

Answer (score 0):

I have a thought that i don't test before:

```
$betasWithACharlie = $alpha->betas()->whereHas('charlies', function ($query) {
    $query->where('beta_id', '!=', 0);
})->get();
```

And try another one:

```
$betasWithACharlie = Alpha::whereHas('betas', function ($query) {
    $query->has('charlies');
});
```